# how to write the if condition part?

Tags: php

there are some links as the following

```
    https://example.com/cart.php
    https://example.com/cart.php?gid=1
    https://example.com/cart.php?gid=2
    https://example.com/cart.php?a=view
    https://example.com/cart.phpcart.php?a=confproduct&i=0
.......
```

i want to add some text on those links page. how to write the if condition?

```
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']=='/cart.php'||......)
```

is there a simple way to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']`, like this:

```
if($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] == "/cart.php"){
    // do stuff
} elseif($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] == "/anotherpage.php"){
    // do other stuff
}
```

Answer (score 2):

How about string comparison?

```
$mystr = "https://example.com/cart.php";
if (0 != strncmp($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], $mystr, strlen($mystr)) { ... }
```

[strncmp](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strncmp.php) only compares the first *n* characters; we pass the count via `strlen`.

Answer (score 1):

Place them in an array and then use [`in_array()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php).

```
$pages = array(
   '/cart.php',
   '/cart.php?gid=1',
   '/cart.php?gid=2',
   '/cart.php?a=view'
);

if(in_array($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], $pages)) {
   // ...
}
```

Comment: @AJ They have different GET params. Assuming he wanted to know about them.

Answer (score 0):

If your links like these are not too many, you can use the method @zhuanzhou said.

Otherwise, why not add a new argument to the uri, like

```
https://example.com/cart.php?rule=1
https://example.com/cart.php?gid=1&rule=1
https://example.com/cart.php?gid=2&rule=1
https://example.com/cart.php?a=view&rule=1
```

then, your code can be:

```
if($_GET['rule'] === 1){
// something here
}
```

Comment: It's a handwork. I mean, you should find the common rule of these uris, then you can process them easily. Add arg is one method, or you can find they have common php filename, or common dir.